# django не видит шаблоны на боевом сервере

Tags: python, django

Всем очень добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При загрузке сайта на боевом сервере линукс джанго стал ругаться на отсутствие шаблона: TemplateDoesNotExist at /home
main/index.html.

web/site.ru/mainApp/views.py in home
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form':form}, locals())

Хотя на локальном сервере все работало. Я подозреваю, что это из-за различий относительных путей на винде и линуксе (разработка проекта ведется на локальной машине под виндой)

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join('templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
form = RequestForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
    new_form = form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Ваш запрос успешно отправлен')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form':form}, locals())
```

Comment: `os.path.join('templates')` — это то же самое, что и просто `'templates'`

Comment: А настройки `TEMPLATE_DIRS` не существует

Comment: спс, действительно, уже не существует

Comment: Заметил, что во вьюхе пичарм подсвечивал main/index в строке return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form':form}, locals()) и выдавал тайтл о том, что шаблон не найден. Но сайт при этом прекрасно работал. Нажал на лампочку, выбрал "configure template directories" и отметил папку temlates как Template Folder. Вьюхи увидели шаблоны. Но на боевом сервере все равно та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением BASE_DIR в начало settings.py и в DIRS:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

...

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```